# How do I index from another array into a tensor tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, q-learning

I am trying to write a deep q-learning network for a problem in AI. I have a function `predict()` that produces a tensor of shape `(None, 3)` taking in an input of shape `(None, 5)`. The 3 in `(None, 3)` corresponds to the q-value of each action that can be taken at each state. Now, in the training step, I have to call `predict()` multiple times and use the result to compute the cost and train the model. For doing this, I also have another data array available called `current_actions` which is a list containing indices of actions taken for a particular state in the previous iterations.

What needs to happen is `current_states_outputs` should be a tensor created from the output of `predict()` in which each row contains only one q-value(as opposed to three from the output of `predict()`) and which q-value should be selected should depend on the corresponding index of `current_actions`.

For example, if `current_states_output = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and `current_actions=[0,2,1]`, the result after the operation should be `[1,6,8]` (updated)

How do I do this?

I have tried the following -

```
    current_states_outputs = self.sess.run(self.prediction, feed_dict={self.X:current_states})
    current_states_outputs = np.array([current_states_outputs[a][current_actions[a]] for a in range(len(current_actions))])
```

I basally ran the session on `predict()` and did the required using normal python methords. But because this severs the connection of the cost from the previous layers of the graph, no training can be done.  So, I need to do this operation staying within tensorflow and keeping everything as a tensorflow tensor itself. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
tf.squeeze(tf.gather_nd(a,tf.stack([tf.range(b.shape[0])[...,tf.newaxis], b[...,tf.newaxis]], axis=2)))
```

The sample code:

```
a = tf.Variable(current_states_outputs)
b = tf.Variable(current_actions)
out = tf.squeeze(tf.gather_nd(a,tf.stack([tf.range(b.shape[0])[...,tf.newaxis], b[...,tf.newaxis]], axis=2)))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
sess.run(out)

#output
[1, 6, 8]
```

Comment: It is producing a value error saying `ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 3
 From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [100,1], [100,1,1].`
I tried out with inputs given as `current_states_outputs = np.random.rand(100, 3)` and 

`current_actions = np.random.randint(0,3,(100,1))`

Comment: The above code works for the example you provided. In your case looks like b[...,tf.newaxis] should be replaced with b.

Comment: Thank you. Replacing `b[...,tf.newaxis]` with b did it.